# References, vectors, std::vector::at and easily usable interfaces

Tags: c++, vector, reference

Recently I have been working with a bit of audio code and though domain experience is not needed to understand the question, I think it may help to get my intention.

I have a controller object with a std::vector of Audio_channel objects. Each audio channel in that vector is there to keep the state of each channel (playing, not playing...). The one particular library I am using works with callbacks so you play a sound you mark the channel as "playing" and when it's done playing a callback is made so you can mark it as "idle". For the purposes of this example, let's assume that Audio_channel::play_something() exists and does as expected: mark as playing and start playing a sound, waiting for the callback when the sound is done.

Anyway, most of the time you get to play sounds through the controller object, like this:

```
int channel=0;
audio_controller.play_some_sound(channel); //It would really do something like this->channels.at(0).play_something();
```

And it will, of course, work since the audio_controller really owns these Audio_channels.

There will be times when you want a channel all to yourself and would do this:

```
Audio_channel c=audio_controller.get_me_this_channel(0); //This returns the channel by reference with vector.at(). Try and catch blocks are ommited. 
c.play_something();
```

And though it will work (since it wraps a library that does not know of these abstractions) I know for a fact that this Audio_channel is a copy of the original and, thus, not queryable from the controller (since any changes aren't reflected).

I can always go:

```
Audio_channel& c=audio_controller.get_me_this_channel(0);
c.play_something();
```

And this time I get the real deal and any changes are reflected everywhere...  Thing is, from the standpoint of "calling code" it may be counterintuitive to force the reference there - specially where no error would ever be emmited by the compiler, since no error exists. There's always pointers but I would like to keep those under the surface. I guess that smart pointers are also an option but, again, I would like to keep it as close to the original code as possible.

What other options can you see here that I may be missing?. I thought about wrapping the Audio_channel into something else that does the dirty reference work and return copies of this other interface... I would be getting into a lot of code redirection and methods that just call the methods of the referenced channel but well...

As said, is there something I may be missing?. I am working with a recent gcc compiler, so C++X11 hot stuff is allowed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: make `get_me_this_channel` return reference

Comment: The actual prototype is Canal_audio& obtener_canal(int) throw(); It does already return the reference. Thanks anyway.

Comment: "specially where no error would ever be emmited by the compiler, since no error exist" there would be if you make Audio_channel noncopyable. Is that an option? It seems to make sense to me since you also say working with a copy has it's own problems.

Comment: unless you are using pointer, there only two way you can do it is the way you did it or `audio_controller.get_me_this_channel(0).play_something();`

Comment: stijn, I tried that too before but if make it noncopyable I won't be able to populate the vector.

Comment: Return a reference, and have the channel type be non-copyable; this way AudioChannel c = …; is illegal, but AudioChannel &c = …; works fine.

Comment: addaon, any comments on how to populate the vector if I can't copy elements inside it?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer myself here but will remain open to any suggestions since this solution seems right, though not optimal.

What I have done is turn the Audio_channel into Audio_channel_nonpublic and keep it private to the controller. The controller now return a wrapper class around the Audio_channel_nonpublic (aptly named Audio_channel) that has a reference to the original one and gets the copy stuff right. The new Audio_channel implements the same public interface as the Audio_channel_nonpublic and forwards each call to the referenced object. This way no client code has to be changed at all.

The result works, but has a lot of forward declarations and chunks of code that could be a bit confusing when I come back to them a few months later... It's documenting time!!.

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

*no error would ever be emmited by the compiler, since no error exists*

If you want an error here, change the design of Audio_channel, with C++11 you can write:

```
class Audio_channel
{
    Audio_channel( const Audio_channel& ) = delete;
    Audio_channel& operator=( const Audio_channel& ) = delete;
    ...
};
Audio_channel c=audio_controller.get_me_this_channel(0);
```

This will cause a compile error. Now calling code is forced to take the return value by reference.

If you really want a value-semantic, like your answer suggests, you are already on the right track. You are implementing the [proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) to a reference of the audio-channel. Something like:

```
class Audio_channel_proxy
{
public:
    Audio_channel_proxy( Audio_channel& c ) : m_channel( c ) {}
    void play_something() { m_channel.play_something(); }
...
private:
    Audio_channel &m_channel;
}
```

By default, I would prefer the first method, forcing a reference is quite common, self-documenting and easy to implement.

The second method is not that common, but also not rare. It has a potential pitfall. Especially if you rename your proxy with Audio_channel: it's not self-documenting.

```
Audio_channel c=audio_controller.get_me_this_channel(0);
```

This line suggests unique ownership of the channel because it's a copy by value. But really it's just an alias to a channel, someone else can also modify. So you better document it well (I would start with the naming). I think you already noticed it. Every time I saw this method, at least one person got it wrong, until he learnt his lesson, including me. Further you need to implement **and** maintain the interface of Audio_channel in the proxy. Just for the syntactic sugar of not been forced to write a reference, it's not really worth it.

On the other hand a proxy has a real value if you want a different behavior of the channel (or at least recognize) if it's called via the audio_controller or someone else directly accesses it. But only start with it if there's a need for it.

Comment: Upvote because I really appreciate the time and knowledge :). I reworked the code a bit to accomodate deleting these methods and though it works on its own, I smashed myself against a wall again when it came to populate the vector... With no copy capabilities these things are not assignable and I can't make it past that. It is a shame since I really need to have a vector of them (there may be a changing number as the program runs)... Changing the internal code so there is a std::vector<Audio_channel *> that is accesed with return * vector.at(index)

Comment: makes references to be enforced. It also makes for a few weird idioms when some other object has to temporarily keep track of a channel that may change later (forces pointers around, but again, makes sense and alternatives such as storing the index exist). I don't know which solution I'll choose but thanks a lot!.

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan if you want a vector of non-copyable objects the C++11 way of doing that, is using std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Audio_channel>>. 
I must admit that I haven't really worked with it so far, but maybe it's a starting point for you.

Comment: Will probably take a look at it later... So far I have a working solution with the answer below but I'd like to learn more. Thanks a lot!.